# Gawk: what exactly should be hostname specific file field?

Tags: awk

I am exploring networking with Gawk.

This [document](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawkinet/html_node/Web-page.html) provides a simple example on how to get content of web page.

This [document](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawkinet/html_node/Special-File-Fields.html) describe each fields of the "socket file".

But there is something I do not understand, what should be `hostname` exactly ?

#### Without proxy

I tried the following:

```
BEGIN {
  RS = ORS = "\r\n"
  HttpService = "/inet/tcp/0/yahoo.com/80"
  print "GET http://www.yahoo.com"     |& HttpService
  while ((HttpService |& getline) > 0)
     print $0
  close(HttpService)
}
```

This returns `HTTP/1.0 400 Invalid HTTP Request`

What should exactly be hostname without a proxy ?

#### With proxy

If I have a proxy, what should it be ? I tried in my company behind the proxy, indicated the proxy hotname, but requests could `not be understood by the server` (proxy response).

```
BEGIN {
  RS = ORS = "\r\n"
  HttpService = "/inet/tcp/0/my.proxy.fr/80"
  print "GET http://www.yahoo.com"     |& HttpService
  while ((HttpService |& getline) > 0)
     print $0
  close(HttpService)
}
```

Comment: `This returns HTTP/1.0 400 Invalid HTTP Request` Well, `GET` is not the only thing to do HTTP, is it? And is `GET http://www.yahoo.com` a valid HTTP request? It's what you get - `Invalid HTTP Request`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Indeed. But I must admit that I do not understand what you want me to understand :(

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server name in `GET` has no `http://` and you have to add `HTTP/1.0`, I think otherwise it's a `HTTP/0.9` protocol, that I doubt is used.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    RS = ORS = "\r\n";
    HttpService = "/inet/tcp/0/yahoo.com/80";
    print "GET www.yahoo.com HTTP/1.0" |& HttpService;
    print "" |& HttpService;
    while ((HttpService |& getline) > 0) print $0;
    close(HttpService);
    exit;              
}' </dev/null
```

But it's better to move to HTTP/1.1 anyway.

Comment: Do you have any server that sends back a non error/problem HTTP code ? google.com sends 500, gnu.org sends a 400, python.org sends back a 403, etc.

Comment: `Do you have any server that sends back a non error/problem HTTP code ?` Yes, yahoo.com and google.com send 301.